# angular 2 router-outlet multiple names

Tags: angular

Hello I have sample routes:

```
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'test/:id', component: TestComponentComponent },
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
{
    path: 'subroute', component: SubRouteComponent,
    children:[
        { path: '' },
        { path: 'article1', component: SubRouteTextComponent },
    ]
},
{ path: 'otherroute', component: OtherRouteComponent, outlet:'second'  },
```

And all work fine except otherroute.
In mine nav template

```
  <a [routerLink]="['/home']" routerLinkActive="active" >Home</a>
  <a [routerLink]="[ '/test', id ]" routerLinkActive="active" >Test</a>
  <a [routerLink]="[ '/subroute' ]" routerLinkActive="active" >Sub route</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/subroute/article1' ]" routerLinkActive="active">SubRoute two</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/',{ outlets: {'second':['otherroute'] }} ]" routerLinkActive="active">Other route</a>
```

And my child route mean  inside of  works as expected but i can not make work witch

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="second" ></router-outlet>
```

I can click on otherroute link and then text appears but route is strange(/home(....)) and all other links are after that broken.

My `<router-outlet name="second" ></router-outlet>` text appears and but `<router-outlet ></router-outlet>` also stays and after `<router-outlet name="second" ></router-outlet>` is visible all the time.

I want to condition to see all two or only one route is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue, if you define a path and outlet, the component is not render.

```
{ path: '', component: OtherRouteComponent, outlet:'second'  }
```

In this way works, with an empty path but is not useful...

Comment: I belive i solved for empty i just create empty route for outlet and link like so: <a [routerLink]="[ '/',{outlets:{'second':'emptyother', primary:['test',id]}}]" routerLinkActive="active" >Test</a>